# Admob ad never displays in View

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to get AdMob ads to display in my android application and have been unable to do so. I have contacted their support and have not received any response in almost a week, so I figured I would now ask for help here.

First some code:
`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<manifest 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:versionCode="1" package="com.foo.application">
  <application>
    <meta-data 
        android:value="admob-publisher-id-here" 
        android:name="ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID" />
  </application>

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Yes, **admob-publisher-id-here** is my real publisher id in the actual manifest file.

`main_layout.xml`

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/adhost" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="20dip" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.foo.application">
  <com.admob.android.ads.AdView 
      android:id="@+id/ad" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      app:backgroundColor="#000000" 
      app:primaryTextColor="#FFFFFF" 
      app:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC"
      app:keywords="android at&amp;t t-mobile iphone blah"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

`attr.xml`

```
<resources>
  <declare-styleable name="com.admob.android.ads.AdView">            
    <attr name="backgroundColor" format="color" />
    <attr name="primaryTextColor" format="color" />
    <attr name="secondaryTextColor" format="color" />
    <attr name="keywords" format="string" />
    <attr name="refreshInterval" format="integer" />
  </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

`MainActivity.java`

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import com.admob.android.ads.AdManager;
import com.admob.android.ads.AdView;

import com.foo.application.R;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private AdView ad;

  public MainActivity ( ) {
        AdManager.setTestDevices ( new String[] {
      // made this up for this
            "012345678994814751742145548AAAAAAA" 
        } );
        AdManager.setTestAction ( "url" );
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate ( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
      super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

        if ( AdManager.isTestDevice ( this ) ) {
          // this logs
            Log.w ( "foo-app", "we are on a test device" );
        }

        ad = ( AdView ) this.findViewById ( R.id.ad );
        if ( ad != null ) {
            ad.setVisibility ( View.VISIBLE );
            ad.setAdListener ( new AdListener () );
        }
    }
}
```

`AdListener.java`

```
package com.foo.application

import android.util.Log;

import com.admob.android.ads.AdView;
import com.admob.android.ads.SimpleAdListener;

class AdListener extends SimpleAdListener {
    @Override
    public void onFailedToReceiveAd ( AdView adView ) {
      // this is what logs
        Log.w ( "foo-app", "failed to receive ad" );
        super.onFailedToReceiveAd ( adView );
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailedToReceiveRefreshedAd ( AdView adView ) {
        Log.w ( "foo-app", "failed to receive refreshed ad" );
        super.onFailedToReceiveRefreshedAd ( adView );
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveAd ( AdView adView ) {
        Log.w ( "foo-app", "receive ad" );
        super.onReceiveAd ( adView );
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveRefreshedAd ( AdView adView ) {
        Log.w ( "foo-app", "receive refreshed ad" );
        super.onReceiveRefreshedAd ( adView );
    }
}
```

In the logcat, i see the following:

```
INFO/AdMobSDK(29541): To get test ads on this device use AdManager.setTestDevices( new String[] { "012345678994814751742145548AAAAAAA" } )
WARN/AdMobSDK(29541): Ignoring requestFreshAd() because we are requesting an ad right now already.
WARN/AdMobSDK(29541): Ignoring requestFreshAd() because we are requesting an ad right now already.
WARN/foo-app(29541): we are on a test device
WARN/foo-app(29541): failed to receive ad
```

The AdListener is indicating that it is unable to retrieve the ad. I have an active data connection, plus I am in Test Mode, so it is supposed to always show an ad, according to the [admob wiki](http://developer.admob.com/wiki/Android#SDK_Integration_Instructions). There are no errors in the logcat, nor is the application force closing at all.

Anyone have any ideas or do you see something I am doing wrong?

**update: I got a response from admob, but all they said was i was creating the aeveiw twice, which I am not**

Comment: I've got the same problem, Did you can resolve this problem at last?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Admob should have included this as a warning, but I digress...

In your layout you have `android:padding="5dip"` this of course causes phones like the G1 to 'lose' some of their available screen real-estate (below 320dip width). Which is of course the minimum width for an admob ad, causing it to fail. Then calling `onFailedToReceiveAd` in the listener with no explanation whatsoever.

The logs only contain

```
WARN/AdMobSDK(347): Ignoring requestFreshAd() because we are requesting an ad right now already.
```

The fix is simple, don't use padding or margins in the root of your layouts that contain ads. Took some experimentation, but it works.

Comment: so if my window is not 320dip width the ad will not show? bah!!! thanks. that fixed it.

Comment: ZOMG Thank you for this!  I was stuck until I found your solution!

Answer (score 0):

Ryan have you set your Admob publisher Id???

```
 <meta-data android:value="YOUR_ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID" 
        android:name="ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID" />
```

Comment: yes, my publisher id is in the manifest before the closing application tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of

```
    if ( ad != null ) {
        ad.setVisibility ( View.VISIBLE );
        ad.setAdListener ( new AdListener () );
    }
```

and seeing if it works, as mine is identical without those lines and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/rltvLayout1"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayoutwebview"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <WebView android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/ad_layout" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/home_layout">
        <com.google.ads.AdView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" ads:adUnitId="put here your id"
            ads:adSize="BANNER" android:id="@+id/adView" ads:refreshInterval="60" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```