# Admob ads will not display when placed inside a tabview

Tags: android, listview, admob, android-tabhost

I've been trying to get my ads to display in this type of layout.
Tabs -> LinearLayout -> ListView -> header. The header is set via `addHeaderView` and is displaying normally. If I were to move the ads anywhere else they display normally (so its not a setup issue). Using ads in the header of a listview works fine in my other projects.

So this seems to be a very specific problem, the ads simply refuse to display when placed in the header of a listview inside a tabhost.

My logs show no activity from admob at all. There is either a bug here or limitation of the sdk. Does anyone have any experience or insight into this issue?

EDIT

I found the solution. It actually had to do with padding that was in the root of my Tabview. For more checkout my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576812/admob-ad-never-displays-in-view/3721410#3721410)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the edit, the issue has to do with padding in the views. I answered another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576812/admob-ad-never-displays-in-view/3721410#3721410)