# Admob ads not showing up

Tags: android, admob

I've got a problem with Admob not showing up Ads...

Here's the LogCat:

```
WARN/AdMobSDK(502): Ignoring requestFreshAd() because we are requesting an ad right now already.
INFO/AdMobSDK(502): No fill.  Server replied that no ads are available (1164ms)
INFO/AdMobSDK(502): No fill.  Server replied that no ads are available (846ms)
```

I've tried test mode, no test mode, emulator, real phone, etc. It never shows anything up, but **I get requests and prints on Admob stats**, like if it ever worked...

AFAIK, I did everything in the Admob Android SDK... the only thing that could be the cause of any problems, IMHO, would be the fact that I'm using tabbed layout with scrollview and then a relativelayout where the ad shows...

Here's a sample of the layout for a tab:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.xxx.xxx"
    android:id="@+id/tababout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FF000000">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FF000000"
    android:padding="10px">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/label_img"
        android:src="@drawable/about_header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/label_know_more_desc"
        style="@style/Desc"
        android:layout_below="@id/label_img"
        android:text="@string/tab_about_know_more_desc" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/bt_know_more"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/label_know_more_desc"
        android:text="@string/tab_about_know_more_bt" />

    <com.admob.android.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/ad" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" myapp:backgroundColor="#000000" myapp:primaryTextColor="#FFFFFF" myapp:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC" />
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And here's the main.xml, not that I think you need it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FF000000">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FF000000"
        android:paddingTop="5px">

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

I've read in [Admob ads will not display when placed inside a tabview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705651/admob-ads-will-not-display-when-placed-inside-a-tabview) that the problem could be the 10px padding I'm throwing in, but even if I disable that, it doesn't work.

I even tried moving the xmlns:myapp to RelativeLayout, but obviously didn't change anything....

Also, I've made my first live ad request over 24 hours ago...

**EDIT**

Ok, now I'm getting somewhere, I've managed to get test ads showing up (my setTestDevices was too late in the onCreate code, I pushed it up to the first lines), but not real ones... am I missing something? I obviously commented out the setTestDevices line and no ads show up

**EDIT 2**

Well, I added two internal ads (I already had internal ads enabled, but no internal ads set), and suddenly ads started showing on my app (not only internal ads).

I guess everything altogether made it work?! :)

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't positioning the ad's in the RelativeLayout (they need a layout_above or layout_below or whatever to specify where to put them).

Also there is a minimum size for admob that you might want to ensure you match, I think it's like 48dip in height at least, not sure what the horizontal is.

Lastly I don't know where you are trying to place your ad's, but it probably would make more sense in your main frame-layout, I have a padding at the bottom of my app which I use for the ad-view.

Edit: also if your app is public check for ad-revenue. Android pre 2.3 allowed ad's to be hidden behind views and still register clicks. I actually made my initial $1 before my ad's were even visible by anyone.

Comment: Will check later on today and let you know how it goes. ;)

Comment: Ok, so I took your advice and put the ad block on the main layout, and if I change its background color to white, and set a fix height, I can see it (the white block), but nothing shows inside the block...

Comment: Also, there are requests on the admob reports, though there are no views/impressions clicks.

Comment: <com.admob.android.ads.AdView     
           android:id="@+id/ad" 
           android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
           android:layout_height="50dip"       
           myapp:backgroundColor="#000000"
           myapp:primaryTextColor="#FFFFFF"
           myapp:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
  />            

That's mine, maybe it will help

Comment: Thanks HaMMeReD, but it's just like mine (though I don't have the layout_gravity attribute setup), what do you have on the code?

Comment: AdManager.setTestDevices( new String[] {                 
         AdManager.TEST_EMULATOR,             // Android emulator
         "MyKey",  // 
         } );

Comment: remember, height 50dip matters, there is a minimum height, I'm pretty sure I am using it, so 49 or less is a no go.

Comment: Still not working...

I had this on the code: 

AdView adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.ad);
adView.requestFreshAd();

But removing it doesn't help also... even with the 50dip fix height and the gravity, still not working... I just see the white (or black, depends on the bgcolor I set it to) block... no ads on it...

Comment: Real ad's don't get delivered 100% of the time, it may be a few days before your request rate picks up.

Comment: So 100 requests and 1 impression (which I never saw) doesn't mean there's something wrong with my setup? I'll keep trying to see if any ads show up anyway...

Comment: 1% fill rate is pretty bad, my fill rates are 60-90%
but depending on your traffic and app category you may only get limited ad's being delivered

Comment: I haven't launched the app yet. I'm just waiting to fix this ads issue (for the Free version of it). Those requests are all mine.

Comment: "No fill.  Server replied that no ads are available"... still... can't figure out what's wrong...

Comment: I have a question about ads: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36389729/ads-are-loading-but-not-showing

Answer (score 0):

Another reason that the AdMob Ads won't show up is that you haven't declared the AdActivity which will display the ads when they are clicked on.  Without the AdActivity declared in my AndroidManifest.xml, I don't see the ads.  With it declared, the Ads show up.

...AndroidManifest.xml...

> ```
> <!--  AdMob -->
> <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
>           android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
> ```

Comment: This question refers to the old way of adding AdMob, which did not use or require AdActivity.

Comment: i have made all the things still ads are not visible at runtime.the area for which i have provided to the adView is being left blank,i have given background attribute still it is not visble,plz help

Comment: I have a question about ads: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36389729/ads-are-loading-but-not-showing