# Ads not showing up?

Tags: java, android, string, google-play, admob

As the title suggests, I am having issues with my first official app. I am trying to use admob, but the ads aren't showing up. I have looked at a ton of other links, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338081/admob-ads-not-showing-up), but I have done everything the answers say, and still no luck (i.e. removing padding from root layout , etc.).

The ad **is showing up in the xml, but not when I actually run it. Here is what the ad looks like in the xml:**

[image: [Image for design view of ad]]

**Here is my main activity's layout:**

```
   <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="34dp">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

**Here are some parts of my manifest:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Button Smasher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

---

```
 <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

**My onCreate:**

```
 private AudioManager mAudioManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main__menu);

        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    }
```

***Banner_ad_unit_id is defined in strings.xml**

**I have followed all the tutorials exactly, and have read all the questions on StackOverflow about this topic.** This is one of those moments when I am just completely lost, as I have spent around 4 hours doing everything I can.

I would really appreciate your help in identifying the issue,

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to show test ads or the real thing. Also your main layout is just showing the AdView - what is in activity_main__menu.xml (double underscore-is that correct?)

Comment: @MorrisonChang What is the difference between test ads or the real thong? All I am trying to do is display ads for the user when I release my app, but I cannot see those ads. My activity_main__menu.xml consists of one two other image buttons and one text view. Thanks for your response, let me know if you need any more information. :)

Comment: @MorrisonChang Also, I will update my question with an image of what the add looks like in the xml.

Comment: Not sure if you are running on emulator but if you was following the quick start toward the end https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start you might have noticed a warning box about test ads / test devices which would lead you here: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/targeting#test_ads

Comment: That 'addTestDevice' code is just for test/development work as AdMob has server side check for fraud. If you can see the test ad as shown in the quick-start link then you are good. Remove 'addTestDevice' for your release code.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Okay, so I don't have enough rep to chat...So here is the code I put:

Comment: @MorrisonChang `AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)        // All emulators
                .addTestDevice("huawei-huawei_y536a1-80717a34c6e3")  // My huawei test phone
                .build();`

Comment: @MorrisonChang But it still isn't showing up?

Comment: 1. Make sure your AdUnit ID correct 2. Try it in Emulator 3. Wait at least 5 minutes before closing app or switching activity away from ad view. If it still doesn't show up after a few tries (and waits) then I would start looking at a network problem

Comment: @MorrisonChang So about the AdUnit ID, i'm not sure if it is correct. Here is how I got it. In my console it said:

Comment: @MorrisonChang Shoud I use this serial number?

Comment: @MorrisonChang 
http://snag.gy/2jGaI.jpg

Comment: No. That serial number in your last screenshot isn't helpful. If you feel like you aren't getting it to work - just to make sure it isn't something in your code have you tried the official Google demo app from github? https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/admob

Comment: @MorrisonChang Okay, so what number do I use? Online it says that the console should display your phone's number, but I can't see it. Thanks for the demo app link though. I really appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: This is getting off topic - you should register for AdMob and see this video: https://youtu.be/FlCBL4TmWME. I was able to create a new ad unit without difficulty. I do not know what you mean when you say 'Online it says that the console should display your phone's number'.

Comment: Have you waited a while? Sometimes it can take a good hour or more to get the first ad