# How do I use Admob on the Android OS?

Tags: android, admob

Using AdMob, how can I give an advertisement in an Android Application?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For **[AdMob Android App Integration](http://developer.admob.com/wiki/Android)**

1. Register or login at admob.com, and click 'Sites & Apps".
2. Click "Add Site/App", and provide the info for your Android App. (Feel free to enter placeholder information if you just want to download the SDK without registering a real app.)
3. Once you've added your site, you will be prompted to download the Android SDK and the integration PDF.
4. The download includes the binaries, documentation, and a sample.

   1. Review the integration PDF at [http://www.admob.com/docs/**AdMob_Android_SDK_Instructions.pdf**](http://www.admob.com/docs/AdMob_Android_SDK_Instructions.pdf)
   2. Read index.html for information on the AdMob SDK's classes and methods
   3. Look at the Lunar Lander sample project to see a working example

For more info you should check http://developer.admob.com/wiki/Android

Note: Description for you app/site on admob is very important, they use all info that appear there to provide your advertisement.

**UPDATE:** Now is called ***Google Mobile Ads SDK*** https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download

and for Admob https://www.google.com/ads/admob/monetize.html

Comment: The page you requested was not found

Please check the URL for proper spelling and capitalization. Or, try one of the following links:

Answer (score 0):

Some more info that may help is [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576812/admob-ad-never-displays-in-view). You have to make sure that the AdMob view is at least 320dip, if it is not, you will never see an ad in your application.