# Is it possible to have an AdView inside of a LinearLayout which shrinks the AdView to 180px width

Tags: android, android-layout, admob, android-linearlayout

I'm implementing a layout for a small screen device.
For testing I'm using a Huawei Ideos U8150 which has a resolution of 240x320.

Because of the small resolution I have a major space problem. So I thought I could put an AdMob AdView and a TextView inside of a horizontal LinearLayout.
The AdView size would take up 3/4 of the width and the TextView 1/4.

In the graphical layout tool everything looks as expected. But when I run the app on the device it doesn't display an ad inside of the AdView. I made the background of the AdView red so I can confirm that the AdView is actually visible. It just doesn't display ads.

I confirmed with `onReceiveAd` that I get ads. And I print the frame of the AdView in that method. Which logs as origin: 0,38 width: 180,47. Looks okay for me too.

So I'm wondering if the AdMob AdView is able to resize its ads so they are displayed correctly. Maybe the things I try are just not possible.

That's my layout:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayoutAds" android:background="#F0F0" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="#FF00"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="foobar"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        ads:refreshInterval="30" 
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#F000"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="999"
        android:textSize="45dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ads won't display if your linearlayout's height becomes less than 50 dp. I have not tried reducing width , but after looking at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576812/admob-ad-never-displays-in-view) it looks like  its not possible to reduce the width to 180 px.

Comment: great. At least for the users of tiny devices. They don't see ads :-)  Just found that on the [AdMob website](http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/intermediate.html): "_The SDK will request whatever size the requesting AdView was instantiated with. **If there isn't enough space on the device's screen to display the ad, nothing will be shown.**_"

Comment: AdMob Ads are 320x50dp.  Your phone has a resolution of 240x320, but is a low density device(1dp = 0.75 px), so it is really 320x426dp.  In portrait mode, AdMob requires the entire width of the screen to display an ad, but in landscape mode, it only needs 3/4 of the width on this device.  Take another look at your logs; if you receive an ad, but there is not enough space to show it, the SDK will log a warning saying something like "Not enough space to show ad!  Wants<320,50>, Has: <240,377>".